# IOS/Objective-C: NSPredicate and NULL values in core data fetch

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch items that do not have a value of 1 in an NSNumber attribute. Some of the items I want to fetch have never had the attribute set at all and therefore have a NSNull value.  How can I fetch items that are not 1 but may be NSNull?

The attribute is an `NSNumber` and I am also a bit confused about whether I should be searching on `1` or `@1`.

The following code is excluding NSNull values when I want to include them:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"&hasserverid!=1"];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can search using only 1. @1 will be treated as a string.

Comment: How about the NSNull question?  values with NULL are getting excluded

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly test for both cases with an OR:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasserverid != YES OR hasserverid == NULL"];
```

By the name of your property, I assume when you say 1 you're actually referring to the value true. Using YES in the predicate format instead of 1 makes your predicate more legible.

Comment: In coredate, data type is Boolean.  In the NSManagedObject, however, it is NSNumber.  So I am not sure, if yes or true are correct.  I am using 1 to mean yes or true, but unless I am mistaken The Boolean in core data is fake.  It really just means NSNumber and therefore could have any value.

Comment: To be clear, I want hasserverid not equal to yes or is equal to  null. My goal is to exclude cases where no has been explicitly selected

Comment: Yes, Core Data boolean's are represented as an NSNumber in Objective-C. Using YES instead of 1 just makes that intent clearer. I've updated the answer to not equal to YES.